# Message received in dbus singal does not match sent data

Tags: c, dbus

I'm trying to receive a message over a dbus signal. When I look at dbus-monitor the bytes being sent are correct. But the contents of the message I receive from the signal is sometimes 3 or 4 messages old. My current assumption is that there is something I need to free or a cache I need to flush in between receiving signals but if sd_bus_unref pMessage I seg fault. Is there something else I should be resetting?

My callback:

```
int dbusCallback(sd_bus_message * pMessage, void * userdata, sd_bus_error * ret_error)
{
    int                   sdbusErr = 0;
    uint8_t *             pReceivedArray;
    eNetworkStateEvents_t returnState;

    /* Read the message */
    sdbusErr = sd_bus_message_read_array(pMessage, 'y',  (const void**) &pReceivedArray, &rxDecodedFrameLength);
        printf("Rx buffer %x %x", pReceivedArray[0], pReceivedArray[1]);

    memcpy(packetDecodedRxBuffer, pReceivedArray, rxDecodedFrameLength);

    // packetDecodedRxBuffer and rxDecodedFrameLength are both global
    return 1;
}
```

Dbus thread:

```
    // Subscribe to the signal
    sd_bus_match_signal(bus,                                   // Bus
                        NULL,                                  // Slot
                        SERVICE_NAME,                          // Sender
                        OBJECT_PATH,                           // Path
                        INTERFACE_NAME,                        // Interface
                        MESSAGE_FROM_SIGNAL,                   // Member
                        dbusCallback,                          // Callback
                        NULL);                                 // Userdata

    for (;;)
    {
        SysMonitorSignalThreadGood(SYSMONITOR_DBUS_THREAD_WATCHDOG_FLAG);

        // Process D-Bus requests
        sdbusErr = sd_bus_process(bus, NULL);

        if (0 > sdbusErr)
        {
            printf("D-Bus: Failed to process bus: %s\n", strerror(-sdbusErr));
            continue;
        }

        // Wait for the next D-Bus request to process
        sdbusErr = sd_bus_wait(bus, 100);

        if (0 > sdbusErr)
        {
            printf("D-Bus: Failed to wait on bus: %s\n", strerror(-sdbusErr));
        }

        tx_thread_sleep(MS_TO_TICKS(30u));
    }

    sd_bus_unref(bus);
}
```

My output including output of dbus-monitor

```
method call time=1632862915.524359 sender=:1.104 -> destination=com.example.example.Module serial=9 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_to_server
array of bytes [
    01 31 40 07 f5 02 4e
]
signal time=1632862915.528742 sender=:1.68 -> destination=(null destination) serial=1279 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_from_server
array of bytes [
    02 31 01 58 3a 9f 4d
]
method return time=1632862915.528998 sender=:1.68 -> destination=:1.104 serial=1280 reply_serial=9
Rx buffer 2 31 // Good!



method call time=1632862915.553558 sender=:1.104 -> destination=com.example.example.Module serial=10 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_to_server
array of bytes [
    01 33 01 01 11
]
signal time=1632862915.563459 sender=:1.68 -> destination=(null destination) serial=1281 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_from_server
array of bytes [
    02 33 01 da 58 a9 7f
]
method return time=1632862915.563786 sender=:1.68 -> destination=:1.104 serial=1282 reply_serial=10
ERROR: D-Bus: Bus call failed: Interrupted system call
ERROR: SD-BUS error occurred: System.Error.EINTR  Interrupted system call
method call time=1632862915.565927 sender=:1.104 -> destination=com.example.example.Module serial=11 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_to_server
array of bytes [
    01 33 01 01 11
]
SetDataRecord Received!!
signal time=1632862915.570788 sender=:1.68 -> destination=(null destination) serial=1283 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_from_server
array of bytes [
    02 33 01 da 58 a9 7f
]
method return time=1632862915.571083 sender=:1.68 -> destination=:1.104 serial=1284 reply_serial=11
Rx buffer 2 31 //Stale :(



method call time=1632862915.613063 sender=:1.104 -> destination=com.example.example.Module serial=12 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_to_server
array of bytes [
    01 33 01 01 11
]
signal time=1632862915.614794 sender=:1.68 -> destination=(null destination) serial=1285 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_from_server
array of bytes [
    02 33 01 da 58 a9 7f
]
method return time=1632862915.614949 sender=:1.68 -> destination=:1.104 serial=1286 reply_serial=12
Rx buffer 2 33 // Good!!


method call time=1632862915.643871 sender=:1.104 -> destination=com.example.example.Module serial=13 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_to_server
array of bytes [
    01 42 07 01
]
signal time=1632862915.648303 sender=:1.68 -> destination=(null destination) serial=1287 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_from_server
array of bytes [
    02 42 01 6d 10 8d 49
]
method return time=1632862915.648444 sender=:1.68 -> destination=:1.104 serial=1288 reply_serial=13
ERROR: Bus call failed: Interrupted system call
ERROR: SD-BUS error occurred: System.Error.EINTR  Interrupted system call
method call time=1632862915.650201 sender=:1.104 -> destination=com.example.example.Module serial=14 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_to_server
array of bytes [
    01 42 07 01
]
SetInstrumentDataStatus Received!!
signal time=1632862915.656238 sender=:1.68 -> destination=(null destination) serial=1289 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_from_server
array of bytes [
    02 42 01 6d 10 8d 49
]
method return time=1632862915.656621 sender=:1.68 -> destination=:1.104 serial=1290 reply_serial=14
Rx buffer 2 33 // Stale :(


method call time=1632862915.714133 sender=:1.104 -> destination=com.example.example.Module serial=15 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_to_server
array of bytes [
    01 42 07 01 00 02 0f 00 00 00 52 69 3d 72
]
signal time=1632862915.719213 sender=:1.68 -> destination=(null destination) serial=1291 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_from_server
array of bytes [
    02 42 01 6d 10 8d 49
]
method return time=1632862915.719308 sender=:1.68 -> destination=:1.104 serial=1292 reply_serial=15
Rx buffer 2 33 // Stale :(



method call time=1632862915.745547 sender=:1.104 -> destination=com.example.example.Module serial=16 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_to_server
array of bytes [
    01 42 07 01 00 02 0f 00 00 00 52 69 3d 72
]
signal time=1632862915.749602 sender=:1.68 -> destination=(null destination) serial=1293 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_from_server
array of bytes [
    02 42 01 6d 10 8d 49
]
method return time=1632862915.749657 sender=:1.68 -> destination=:1.104 serial=1294 reply_serial=16
Rx buffer 2 42 // Good!!



method call time=1632862915.777391 sender=:1.104 -> destination=com.example.example.Module serial=17 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_to_server
array of bytes [
    01 31 03 2d e5 d7 a1
]
signal time=1632862915.780942 sender=:1.68 -> destination=(null destination) serial=1295 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_from_server
array of bytes [
    02 31 01 58 3a 9f 4d
]
method return time=1632862915.781538 sender=:1.68 -> destination=:1.104 serial=1296 reply_serial=17
Rx buffer 2 42 // Stale :(



method call time=1632862915.857045 sender=:1.104 -> destination=com.example.example.Module serial=18 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_to_server
array of bytes [
    01 31 03 2d e5 d7 a1
]
signal time=1632862915.857262 sender=:1.68 -> destination=(null destination) serial=1297 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_from_server
array of bytes [
    02 31 01 58 3a 9f 4d
]
method return time=1632862915.857288 sender=:1.68 -> destination=:1.104 serial=1298 reply_serial=18
Rx buffer 2 42 // Stale :(



method call time=1632862915.887795 sender=:1.104 -> destination=com.example.example.Module serial=19 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_to_server
array of bytes [
    01 31 03 2d e5 d7 a1
]
signal time=1632862915.890850 sender=:1.68 -> destination=(null destination) serial=1299 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_from_server
array of bytes [
    02 31 01 58 3a 9f 4d
]
method return time=1632862915.891610 sender=:1.68 -> destination=:1.104 serial=1300 reply_serial=19
Rx buffer 2 42 // Stale :(



method call time=1632862915.916836 sender=:1.104 -> destination=com.example.example.Module serial=20 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_to_server
array of bytes [
    01 31 03 2d e5 d7 a1
]
signal time=1632862915.920036 sender=:1.68 -> destination=(null destination) serial=1301 path=/; interface=example.DBus.Module; member=message_from_server
array of bytes [
    02 31 01 58 3a 9f 4d
]
method return time=1632862915.920089 sender=:1.68 -> destination=:1.104 serial=1302 reply_serial=20
Rx buffer 2 31 //Good
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem ended up being that I was sometimes receiving `System.Error.EINTR` errors when the dbus calls successfully sent. Because of this error I was assuming a failure and sending again, thus multiple replies. Ignoring those errors stops my sending multiple of the same requests and fixes my problem.

There is a [sd_bus_flush](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man3/sd_bus_close.3.html) call but that is for ensuring messages are sent before closing the bus, for receiving messages there is no sort of cache or flush mechanism.